# Can a class with all private members be a POD class?

Tags: c++

I've heard before that POD types cannot have private data -- but according to the C++0x draft I have the requirement is looser (emphasis mine):

> has the **same access control** (Clause 11) for all non-static data members

which seems to suggest that private data is okay so long as it's all private. I don't have a copy of C++03 though to check...

Would then, `WindowsApi::Uuid` be a POD class?

```
namespace WindowsApi
{
    class Uuid
    {
        union
        {
            ::UUID asUuid; //Win32's UUID struct
            unsigned __int64 asInt64s[2];
            unsigned __int32 asInt32s[4];
        };
    public:
        Uuid() {}
        Uuid(::UUID sourceStructure) : asUuid(sourceStructure) {}
        operator ::UUID() { return asUuid; }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++03 still does not allow non-static private or protected data in POD classes. This requirement is specified in the definition of *aggregate*

> An aggregate is an array or a class (clause 9) with no user-declared constructors (12.1), **no private or protected non-static data members (clause 11)**, no base classes (clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3).

and POD class must be an aggregate first.

Comment: So this rule got relaxed in C++0x then? (I don't see anything about aggregates in the C++0x draft around the definition of POD types)

Answer (score 13):

> I've heard before that POD types cannot have private data

In C++03 POD types cannot have private data (see AndreyT's answer).

However the definition of POD has been changed in C++0x (See `9/10`).

As per [n3225](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3225.pdf)

> A POD struct is a class that is both a **trivial class and a standard-layout class**, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types).
>   ...
>   ...
>
> A POD class is a class that is either a POD struct or a POD union.

That means

```
struct demo
{
   private:
      int a, b;
};
```

is POD in C++0x because `demo` is both trivial and **standard layout**.

The definition of Standard layout is in section `9/7`

> A standard-layout class is a class that:
>
> - has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
> - has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
> - **has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members**,
> - has no non-standard-layout base classes,
> - either has no non-static data members in the most-derived class and at most one base class with
>     non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
> - has no base classes of the same type as the ﬁrst non-static data member.11

.

> Would then, WindowsApi::Uuid be a POD class?

Nopes! `WindowsApi::Uuid` is neither POD in C++03 nor in C++0x. A trivial class is a class that has a **trivial default constructor** (12.1) and is trivially copyable. `WindowsApi::Uuid` has a non trivial default constructor.

> So this rule got relaxed in C++0x then?

Yes! (Considering Clause 11)

Also check out the [FAQ entry on Aggregates and PODs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4178175/what-are-aggregates-and-pods-and-how-why-are-they-special)

Comment: What's the definition of 'trivial' then? :)

Comment: @bdonlan : A trivial class is a class that has a trivial default constructor (12.1) and is trivially copyable.

Comment: @Parasoon: Oops.. forgot the default destructor :P Didn't mean for that bit. +1

Answer (score -1):

According to my n3225 C++0x draft, `WindowsApi::Uuid` is a POD class.

From page 219:
A POD struct is a class that is both a trivial class and a standard-layout class, and has no non-static data members of type non-POD struct, non-POD union (or array of such types).

A trivial class is a class that has a trivial default constructor and is trivially copyable:

A trivially copyable class is a class that:

- has no non-trivial copy constructors (12.8),
- has no non-trivial move constructors (12.8),
- has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
- has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and
- has a trivial destructor (12.4).

A standard-layout class is a class that:

- has no non-static data members of type non-standard-layout class (or array of such types) or reference,
- has no virtual functions (10.3) and no virtual base classes (10.1),
- **has the same access control (Clause 11) for all non-static data members**,
- has no non-standard-layout base classes,
- either has no non-static data members in the most-derived class and at most one base class with non-static data members, or has no base classes with non-static data members, and
- has no base classes of the same type as the first non-static data member.

Since `WindowsApi` doesn't violate any of these constraints, it will be a valid POD class under C++0x.  As AndreyT mentions, this is a more generous wording than C++03.

Comment: I don't see any user-defined copy constructor in that class. Do the constructor and the conversion operator combine to form a copy constructor?

Comment: It does not have a user defined copy constructor. `::WindowsApi::Uuid` is my class, `::UUID` is the one defined by Windows. (Note the CaPs difference)

Comment: @Billy : You have a non trivial default constructor though. `WindowsApi::Uuid` is not a POD.

Comment: @Billy: Thanks!  Somehow I misread ::UUID as the name of the class.  I'll update.  @Prasoon: A default constructor is one that can be called without any parameters.  The only defined constructor isn't one.